# Memcpy uint32_t into char*

Tags: c++, arrays, char, memcpy, uint32

I testing a bit with different formats and stuff like that. And we got a task where we have to put uint32_t into char*. This is the code i use:

```
void appendString(string *s, uint32_t append){
    char data[4];
    memcpy(data, &append, sizeof(append));
    s->append(data);
}

void appendString(string *s, short append){
    char data[2];
    memcpy(data, &append, sizeof(append));
    s->append(data);
}
```

From string to char is simple and we have to add multiple uints into the char*. So now i'm just calling it like:

```
string s;
appendString(&s, (uint32_t)1152); //this works
appendString(&s, (uint32_t)640); //this also works
appendString(&s, (uint32_t)512); //this doesn't work
```

I absolutely don't understand why the last one isn't working properly. I've tested multiple variations of transform this. One way always gave me output like (in bits): 00110100 | 00110101 ... so the first 2 bits are always zero, followed by 11 and then for me some random numbers.. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: How does `s->append` know how much data there is?  Is it templated?

Comment: data is not ‚\0‘ terminated.

Comment: Why are you using `std::string` for binary data? Append is assuming what it is a C style string - i.e. null terminated

Comment: do not use `std::string` for binary data, use `std::vector<uint8_t>` instead

Comment: @Slava: That probably is a better idea, but `std::string` is length-based not terminator-based, and can handle embedded NUL just fine.... if used correctly.

Comment: @BenVoigt I know it can, but `std::string` has too many links with zero based strings, it would be much less error prone to use vector. For example you can override `std::ostream::operator<<` to dump binary data properly, wityhout it it would reject to printe etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `string` is `std::string`, then the single-argument version of `std::string::append` is being used, which assumes the input data is NUL-terminated.  Yours is not, but `append` will go looking for the first NUL byte anyway.

512 is 0x00000100, which on a little endian machine is 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00.  Since the first byte is NUL, `std::string::append()` stops there.

Use the version of `std::string::append()` where you pass in the length.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Now i feel dump^^ so simple but so easy to forget.